# Decode Map keys in call to Struct.toHuman()

Tags: polkadot-js, btreemap

I have the following struct, where Characters is the [newtype idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html) around `Vec<u8>`.

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, RuntimeDebug)]
pub struct OperationData {
  config: BTreeMap<Characters, Vec<Characters>>
}
```

Now, If I submit an extrinsic call to save such structure:

```
{
  config: { hasher: [ 'Sha2_256', 'Blake3_256' ] },
}
```

The structure is stored correctly but upon reading (for instance in polkadot ui) I get:

```
{
  config: {
    0x686173686572: [
      Sha2_256
      Blake3_256
    ]
  }
}
```

It appears that the call to `Struct.toHuman()` does not attempt any conversion of the UTF-8 hex-encoded bytes of the key of the map entry:

```
h  a  s  h  e  r
68 61 73 68 65 72
```

*It does, however, decode the bytes inside the value of the map entry.*

Is there a way to indicate the decoder to decode the map entry keys as well? Any good reason why Map keys are disregarded despite their type association?

Answer (score 1):

The `toHuman()` output is not configurable. Bear in mind that this is a convenience function, not really meant to be used for anything but simple inspection.